# Draw automatically the first vertice of a path with Open Layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'd like to help the user to input an orientation for a segment with OpenLayers.

I have that form where user can input the bearing for a point, but I would like to help him by :

- start drawing the first vertice of a segment on the map when the user clicks on a button, (that first vertice being a known point)
- then the user just has to click for the second vertice, and bearing is computed automatically.

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mf3jyyqu/6/) or SO snippet below.

I'm almost done : I can compute the bearing when a segment is drawn. But there's an exception at the very end of the script : I can't get OL to draw automatically the first point of my segment.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

```html
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>
</body>



<script>
  var CONSTANTS = {
    MAP_FROM_PROJECTION: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // Transform from WGS 1984
    MAP_TO_PROJECTION: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") // to Spherical Mercator Projection
  };

  function radians(n) {
    return n * (Math.PI / 180);
  }

  function degrees(n) {
    return n * (180 / Math.PI);
  }


  function computeBearing(startLat, startLong, endLat, endLong) {
    startLat = radians(startLat);
    startLong = radians(startLong);
    endLat = radians(endLat);
    endLong = radians(endLong);

    var dLong = endLong - startLong;

    var dPhi = Math.log(Math.tan(endLat / 2.0 + Math.PI / 4.0) / Math.tan(startLat / 2.0 + Math.PI / 4.0));
    if (Math.abs(dLong) > Math.PI) {
      if (dLong > 0.0) dLong = -(2.0 * Math.PI - dLong);
      else dLong = (2.0 * Math.PI + dLong);
    }

    return (degrees(Math.atan2(dLong, dPhi)) + 360.0) % 360.0;
  }


  map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
  map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(3, 47).transform(CONSTANTS.MAP_FROM_PROJECTION, CONSTANTS.MAP_TO_PROJECTION), 6);


  var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer");

  map.addLayers([lineLayer]);

  var lineControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
    handlerOptions: {
      maxVertices: 2,
      freehandMode: function(evt) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    featureAdded: function(feature) {
      var drawnLinePoints = feature.geometry.getVertices();
      var lonlat1 = drawnLinePoints[0].transform(CONSTANTS.MAP_TO_PROJECTION, CONSTANTS.MAP_FROM_PROJECTION);
      var lonlat2 = drawnLinePoints[1].transform(CONSTANTS.MAP_TO_PROJECTION, CONSTANTS.MAP_FROM_PROJECTION);
      var bearingValue = computeBearing(lonlat1.y, lonlat1.x, lonlat2.y, lonlat2.x);
      console.log(bearingValue);
    }
  });
  map.addControl(lineControl);
  lineControl.activate();


  var handler;
  for (var i = 0; i < map.controls.length; i++) {
    var control = map.controls[i];
    if (control.displayClass === "olControlDrawFeature") {
      handler = control.handler;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Here I have an exception in the console : I would like
  // OL to draw hat point automatically.
  handler.addPoint(new OpenLayers.Pixel(50, 50));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mf3jyyqu/9/) for the solution.

tldr :

```
// draw the first point as I needed, as if a user has clicked on the map
handler.modifyFeature(new OpenLayers.Pixel(50, 50), true); 

// draw a first point on the map (not clicked). 
// This will be the initial point where the "cursor" is on the map, as long as 
// the user hasn't hovered onto the map with its mouse. This make the blue 
// line showing current segment to appear, without this segment is drawn but 
// no feedback is given to the user as long as he hasn't clicked.
handler.addPoint(new OpenLayers.Pixel(50, 50)); //
```

Answer (score 1):

`OpenLayers.Handler.Path.addPoint` works on `OpenLayers.Pixel`, not `OpenLayers.LonLat`:

```
/**
 * Method: addPoint
 * Add point to geometry.  Send the point index to override
 * the behavior of LinearRing that disregards adding duplicate points.
 *
 * Parameters:
 * pixel - {<OpenLayers.Pixel>} The pixel location for the new point.
 */
addPoint: function(pixel) {
    this.layer.removeFeatures([this.point]);
    var lonlat = this.layer.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(pixel); 
    this.point = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat)
    );
    this.line.geometry.addComponent(
        this.point.geometry, this.line.geometry.components.length
    );
    this.layer.addFeatures([this.point]);
    this.callback("point", [this.point.geometry, this.getGeometry()]);
    this.callback("modify", [this.point.geometry, this.getSketch()]);
    this.drawFeature();
    delete this.redoStack;
}
```

I actually see no good way of achieving this other than adding an `addPointByLonLat` method:

```
OpenLayers.Handler.Path.prototype.addPointByLonLat = function(lonLat) {
    this.layer.removeFeatures([this.point]);
    this.point = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat)
    );
    this.line.geometry.addComponent(
        this.point.geometry, this.line.geometry.components.length
    );
    this.layer.addFeatures([this.point]);
    this.callback("point", [this.point.geometry, this.getGeometry()]);
    this.callback("modify", [this.point.geometry, this.getSketch()]);
    this.drawFeature();
    delete this.redoStack;
};
```

Or subclass as your own handler class (propbably cleaner).

Notes:

- `addPoint` is not an API method (so `addPointByLonLat` is also not). This may result in problem on version changes.
- Don't use the compressed/minified JS in development and check docs on methods you use.
- Next time consider asking on https://gis.stackexchange.com/.
- Consider asking for a code review on your JS.

Comment: Thank you ver much for your answer. This JS code isn't my production code, that's just a quick POC. Yes, I made a mistake on the type of argument given to the function - I tried so many things that I probably  copied / paste wrong bits of code. However real problem is, even with the LonLat object or by using the prototype you kindly showed to me, There's an error when the page loads (see updated fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/mf3jyyqu/6/)

Comment: @Mat Sorry, almost impossible to debug if you use the compressed JS. Switch to dev scripts and trace it.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Here it is with the uncompressed file : http://jsfiddle.net/mf3jyyqu/8/. Problem seems to occur only if I want to draw the point just after adding the control to the map. If I delay it, and draw the first point only after the click on a button let's say, no problem.

Comment: `this.point` is `null` on start. Check for this case before passing it to `this.layer.removeFeatures([this.point]);`

Comment: Yep, I saw that ^^. So is `this.line`. Problem is, if I bypass all function calls where something is undefined, nothing is drawned. There's probably an initialization function I have to call somewhere along the way, but can't find which one nor where...

Comment: I finally have the desired behavior : http://jsfiddle.net/mf3jyyqu/9/. But that's kind of a hack, I had to put breakpoints everywhere to see what function call initialized objects the right way (and that was the modifyFeature one). I'm gonna dig to find the proper way to do this.

Comment: @Mat Ask in the OpenLayers mailing list. People are quite helpful there. Or on the GIS stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use insertXY(x,y) function in order to insert a point with geographic coordinates
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Path-js.html#OpenLayers.Handler.Path.insertXY

```
    lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(1,45);
    lonlat.transform(CONSTANTS.MAP_FROM_PROJECTION,CONSTANTS.MAP_TO_PROJECTION);
    handler.createFeature(new OpenLayers.Pixel(100, 100));
    handler.insertXY(lonlat.lon,lonlat.lat);
    handler.drawFeature();
```

You can check it here with a fork of your original jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mefnpbn2/